# programmatically executing and terminating a long-running batch process in python

Tags: python, operating-system, batch-file, subprocess, multiprocessing

I have been searching for a way to start and terminate a long-running "batch jobs" in python. Right now I'm using "os.system()" to launch a long-running batch job inside each child process. As you might have guessed, "os.system()" spawns a new process inside that child process (grandchild process?), so I cannot kill the batch job from the grand-parent process. To provide some visualization of what I have just described:

```
Main (grandparent) process, with PID = AAAA
          |
          |------> child process with PID = BBBB
                         |
                         |------> os.system("some long-running batch file)
                                  [grandchild process, with PID = CCCC]
```

So, my problem is I cannot kill the grandchild process from the grandparent...

My question is, is there a way to start a long-running batch job inside a child process, and being able to kill that batch job by just terminating the child process? 
What are the alternatives to os.system() that I can use so that I can kill the batch-job from the main process ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

[**subprocess**](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module is the proper way to spawn and control processes in Python.

from the docs:

> The subprocess module allows you to
>   spawn new processes, connect to their
>   input/output/error pipes, and obtain
>   their return codes. **This module
>   intends to replace several other,
>   older modules and functions**, such as:
>
> **os.system**
> os.spawn
> os.popen
> popen2
> commands

so... if you are on Python 2.4+, `subprocess` is the replacement for `os.system`

for stopping processes, check out the `terminate()` and `communicate()` methods of `Popen` objects.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a Posix-compatible system (e.g., Linux or OS X) and no Python code has to be run after the child process, use `os.execv`. In general, avoid `os.system` and use the `subprocess` module instead.

Answer (score -1):

If you want control over start and stop of child processes you have to use threading.  In that case, look no further than Python's [`threading`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) module.